# Find Unique Count Postgresql query into hivesql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, hiveql

I want to get unique customer counts. I have reference of postgresql query. Could you please convert this query into HiveSql

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) Total_profiles,
    COUNT(distinct user_id) FITLER (WHERE age BETWEEN 18 AND 12) as age_less_than_20
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE 
    profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Comment: How is MySQL involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use case expressions:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) Total_profiles,
    COUNT(distinct case when age BETWEEN 18 AND 12 then user_id else null end) as age_less_than_20
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE 
    profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

One more method for counting distinct is size(collect_set()):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) Total_profiles,
    size(collect_set(case when age BETWEEN 18 AND 12 then user_id else null end)) as age_less_than_20
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE 
    profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```